# Plotly-Dash: Adding new yaxis per selected df column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a basic dash app that graphs some data from a dictionary of dataframes. The first dropdown selects the df, while the second selects the columns of the df to be plotted.

This works well, but I can't seem to add a new yaxis for each of the plotted columns. I have a large number of columns in each df and they change depending on the df that is selected.

First, I tried to change the updateGraph callback to include `yaxis=i` after defining x, y & name. Looking at the documentation, it seems that I can define the yaxis in `go.Scatter` but that I would need to set them as 'y2', 'y3, 'y4' etc. I've also tried to update the layout via `go.Figure.add_trace` in this way but neither has worked. The code is below, where `dict_main` is a dictionary of dataframes of various sizes.

All help is appreciated!

```
data = list(dict_main.keys())
channels = dict_main[data[0]]

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Div([
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='data-dropdown',
                options=[{'label': speed, 'value': speed} for speed in data],
                value=list(dict_main.keys())[0],
                searchable=False
            ),
        ], style={'width': '49%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
        html.Div([
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='channel-dropdown',
                multi=True
            ),
        ], style={'width': '49%', 'display': 'inline-block'}
        ),
        html.Div([
            dcc.Graph(
                id='Main-Graph',
            ),
        ], style={'width': '98%', 'display': 'inline-block'}
        )
    ]
)

@app.callback(
    Output('channel-dropdown', 'options'),
    [Input('data-dropdown', 'value')])
def update_date_dropdown(speed):
    return [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in dict_main[speed]]

@app.callback(
    Output('Main-Graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('channel-dropdown', 'value')],
    [State('data-dropdown', 'value')])
def updateGraph(channels, speed):
    if channels:

        return go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter(x=dict_main[speed].index, y=dict_main[speed][i], name=i, yaxis='y2') for i in channels])
    else:
        return go.Figure(data=[])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

UPDATE! This works, although some small changes to color and position are still needed - Thanks to @Philipp for all the help;

```
@app.callback(
    Output('Main-Graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('channel-dropdown', 'value')],
    [State('rpm-dropdown', 'value')])
def updateGraph(channels, test):
    if channels:
        j=1
        my_layout = {}
        my_axis = list("")
        for index, column in enumerate(list(channels)):
            my_layout['yaxis' + str(j) if j > 1 else 'yaxis'] = {}
            my_layout['yaxis' + str(j) if j > 1 else 'yaxis']['title'] = column
            my_layout['yaxis' + str(j) if j > 1 else 'yaxis']['overlaying'] = 'y' if j > 1 else 'free'
            my_layout['yaxis' + str(j) if j > 1 else 'yaxis']['anchor'] = 'free'
            my_layout['yaxis' + str(j) if j > 1 else 'yaxis']['side'] = 'left'
            my_axis.append('y' + str(j) if j > 1 else 'y')
            j+=1
        return go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter(x=dict_main[test].index, y=dict_main[test][column], name=column, yaxis=my_axis[index]) for index, column in enumerate(channels)],layout=my_layout)

    else:
        return go.Figure(data=[])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define every y-axis in the layout property of your graph (right now you're only setting the data property). See this [example](https://plot.ly/python/multiple-axes/#multiple-axes).

If you don't want to draw all y-axes (if your df has many columns) you have to set some of them invisible via setting variables like [overlaying, ticks, showticklabels, showgrid, zeroline] (you can find info about them [here](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-yaxis-overlaying)) but they still have to be defined accordingly in the layout so you can refer to them in the scatter function.

Comment: I have a large number of columns and they change depending on the df that is selected. I want to try and add the additional yaxis dynamically. I.e;

go.Figure([go.Scatter(x=dict_main[test].index, y=dict_main[test][i], name=i, yaxis=i) for i in channels])

Rather than having to define them manually. Any ideas?

Comment: go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter(x=dict_main[test].index, y=dict_main[test][i], name=i, yaxis=i) for i in channels], layout=my_layout) where my_layout is something you can build dynamically with the help of the example I have linked.

Comment: To help you a little more out with some "pseudo" code:my_layout={} for index, column in enumerate(list(df.columns)): my_layout['yaxis'+i] = {} my_layout['yaxis'+i][''title"] = column. Note that there is no yaxis0 and also no yaxis1, they go: yaxis, yaxis2, yaxis3. You have to make it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the support! I've tried to implement this and think I have the logic to get yaxis number correctly. I'm just wondering where to declare my_layout? I've updated my original question to show what I mean.

Comment: my_layout has to be declared in your updateGraph function with my_layout={} before your loop. Note that you are right that in your scatter you have to refer to the yaxis with y, y2, y3 while in the layout you call them yaxis, yaxis2, ayxis3.

Comment: Your layout in the end will be a dictionary of dictionaries which you have to create yourself. While every key in your top level dictionary will be representative for one yaxis and the inner dictionaries hold all the attributes that you can find here: https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-yaxis-overlaying for the axis.

Comment: As in; def updateGraph(channels, test, my_layout)? I've tried to build it dynamically and put it in my question for you to see, but get the error 'unresolved reference'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202895/discussion-between-philipp-and-iceberg-slim).

Comment: I've updated the question with a few new attempts but they didn't work, although I feel like I'm getting closer now.

Comment: I've noted two things in the chat about your current code that you have to fix.